# Weird correlation results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation, multi-index

I'm trying to calculate the correlation between 2 multi-index dataframes(a and b) in two ways:

1)calculate the date-to-date correlation directly with `a.corr(b)` which returns a result `X`

2)take the mean values for all dates and calculate the correlation
`a.mean().corr(b.mean())` and I got a result `Y`.

I made a scatter plot and in this way I needed both dataframes with the same index.
I decided to calculate:
`a.mean().corr(b.reindex_like(a).mean())` and I again achieved the value `X`.
It's strange for me because I expected to get 'Y'. I thought that the `corr` function reindex the dataframes one to another. If not, what is this value `Y` I am getting?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer - when I do the reindex, I cut most of the values. One of the dataframes consists of only one value per date, so the mean is equal to this value.